# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my little project.

Here is my controler

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/loginPage" )
public class LoginController
{
private static final String VN_LOGIN_FORM      = "login/LoginForm";
private static final String VN_HOME_FORM       = "redirect:../home.html";
String VN_LOGIN_FAIL_FROM = "redirect:../loginPage /login.html";

//   @Autowired
private AccountService      act;

private EmployeeService     em;

@RequestMapping( value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String getRegistrationForm( Model model )
{
    model.addAttribute( "user", new AccountForm( ) );
    return VN_LOGIN_FORM;
}

@RequestMapping( value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String postRegistrationForm( @ModelAttribute( "user" ) AccountForm form )
{
    Account temp = toAccount( form );
    Account found = act.getAccount( temp.getUsername( ) );
    java.util.List<Employee> list = em.getNewEmployees( );

    if ( found != null && found.getPassword( ).equals( temp.getPassword( ) ) )
    {
        return VN_HOME_FORM;
    }
    return VN_LOGIN_FAIL_FROM;

}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder( WebDataBinder binder )
{
    binder.setAllowedFields( new String[ ] { "username", "password", "confirmPassword", "firstName", "lastName", "email",
            "marketingOk", "acceptTerms" } );
}

private static Account toAccount( AccountForm form )
{
    Account account = new Account( );
    account.setUsername( form.getUsername( ) );
    account.setPassword( form.getPassword( ) );
    return account;
}
```

}

Here is my jps page.

```
    <form:form action="." modelAttribute="user" method="POST"
    class="login">
    <form:errors path="*">
        <div class="warning alert">
            <spring:message code="error.global" />
        </div>
    </form:errors>
    <div>
        <label for="username">${username}</label>
        <form:input name="username" id="login" path="username"
            cssErrorClass="short error" value="username" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <label for="password">${password}</label>
        <form:password path="password" name="password" value="1111111111" />
    </div>
    <div class="login-submit">
        <button type="submit" value="" class="login-button">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="forgot-password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-reset">Forgot your
            password?</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Here is the exception trace:

```
09:31:49,069 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login.LoginForm_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(LoginForm_jsp.java:364)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login.LoginForm_jsp._jspService(LoginForm_jsp.java:174)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
```

Here is info from my beans-web.xml

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/loginPage/login.html" view-name="login/LoginForm" />
```

How  i access the page :

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc/loginPage/login.html
```

I don't understand where's the probleme.

Comment: This might be useful for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787938/spring-mvc-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003809/java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-f

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have configured only `<mvc:view-controller>` in your `beans-web.xml`. In order for spring to inject user object, the controller needs to be scanned as well. Below tags are required to register the controllers and the handler mapping. If you have configured the below post your complete config in your OP.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="you controller package goes here" />
```

If your dispatcher servlet is set to handle *.html, then you don't need `<mvc:view-controller>`. Simple passing through the controller should solve your issue.